# Python dictionary: Sum of all the values for all the "distinct first word" in the "key."

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, nlp, text-processing

I have a dictionary that has a combination of two words as "keys", and certain number as its "values."
Example:

```
bigram_counts = {(u',', u'which'): 1, (u'of', u'the'): 2, ('<UNK>', u'by'): 2, (u'in', '<UNK>'): 1, ('<UNK>', u'charge'): 1, (u'``', '<UNK>'): 2, (u'The', u'and'): 1, ('<UNK>', u'reports'): 1, (u'an', '<UNK>'): 1, (u'election', u'was'): 1, ('<UNK>', u'primary'): 2, (u'that', '<UNK>'): 1, (u'that', u'the'): 1, (u'and', u'Fulton'): 1, ('<UNK>', u'to'): 1, (u'primary', u'election'): 1, (u'had', u'been'): 1, (u'primary', u'which'): 1, (u'The', '<UNK>'): 1, (u'the', u'election'): 2, (u'irregularities', u'took'): 1, (u',', u'``'): 1, ('<UNK>', u'that'): 1, ('<UNK>', u'of'): 2, (u'the', u'City'): 2, (u'in', u'which'): 1, (u'jury', '<UNK>'): 1, ('<UNK>', u'.'): 2, ('<UNK>', u'the'): 1, (u'of', u"Atlanta's"): 1, ('<UNK>', u'jury'): 1, (u'had', '<UNK>'): 1, (u'election', '<UNK>'): 1, (u'Fulton', u'County'): 1, ('<UNK>', u'``'): 2, (u'of', '<UNK>'): 1, ('<UNK>', u'said'): 2, (u'place', u'.'): 1, ('<UNK>', u'and'): 1, (u'election', u','): 1, (u"Atlanta's", '<UNK>'): 1, (u'which', u'the'): 1, (u'been', '<UNK>'): 1, (u'charge', u'of'): 1, (u'County', '<UNK>'): 1, (u'by', u'Fulton'): 1, (u'reports', u'of'): 1, (u'manner', u'in'): 1, ('<UNK>', u'an'): 1, (u"''", u'in'): 1, (u'the', '<UNK>'): 2, (u'said', '<UNK>'): 1, (u'Fulton', '<UNK>'): 1, (u'The', u'jury'): 1, (u'Atlanta', u"''"): 1, (u'``', u'irregularities'): 1, (u'in', u'the'): 1, (u'took', u'place'): 1, (u'for', u'the'): 1, (u'irregularities', u"''"): 1, ('<S>', u'The'): 3, (u"''", u'that'): 1, (u'City', '<UNK>'): 1, (u'which', u'was'): 1, (u"''", u'for'): 1, (u'was', '<UNK>'): 2, (u'jury', u'had'): 1, (u'said', u'in'): 1, (u'by', '<UNK>'): 1, ('<UNK>', u"''"): 1, ('<UNK>', u'irregularities'): 1, (u'to', '<UNK>'): 1, (u'.', '</S>'): 3, (u'of', u'Atlanta'): 1, ('<UNK>', u','): 1, (u'City', u'of'): 1, (u'and', '<UNK>'): 1, (u'which', u'had'): 1, (u'the', u'manner'): 1, ('<UNK>', '<UNK>'): 12}
```

I want to return a new dictionary that has the sum of all the values for all the "distinct first word" in the "key," and the second word could be any word.
Example:
In bigram_counts above, there are 4 elements that has " u'of' " as their "first word" in key and sum of their values is 5.

I also have another dictionary that has all the "distinct words" to help in calculation.
Example:

```
unigram_counts = {u'and': 2, u'City': 2, u"Atlanta's": 1, u'primary': 2, u'an': 1, u"''": 3, u'election': 3, u'in': 3, '<UNK>': 35, u'said': 2, u'for': 1, u'had': 2, u',': 2, u'been': 1, u'.': 3, u'to': 1, u'charge': 1, u'which': 3, u'Atlanta': 1, u'was': 2, u'``': 3, u'jury': 2, u'that': 2, '<S>': 4, u'took': 1, u'The': 3, u'by': 2, u'Fulton': 2, u'of': 5, u'reports': 1, u'irregularities': 2, u'County': 1, u'place': 1, u'the': 7, '</S>': 1, u'manner': 1}
```

Actually, unigram_counts already has the sum I want. However, I need to compute the sum from bigram_counts and match it against the values of unigram_counts.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Baruchel is right that this is probably bad structure to handle this, but anyway:

```
unigram_counts = collections.defaultdict(int)
for (first, _), val in bigram_counts.iteritems():
    unigram_counts[first] += val
```

It seems to work

Comment: Yes, it seems to work. But one element is missing in new dictionary. It is for the token '</S>'.
Check yourself:
print(len(unigram_counts)) #36
print(len(ret)) #35

Beside, Baruchel, @MateuszL can you please suggest be about a better way for storing such data structure. Thanks.

Comment: A trie is better =)

Comment: @New_Coder  '</S> is a second word, so it is not present in unigram_counts. Its first word is '.' and is present.

Comment: @New_Coder To tell the truth, we don't know the rest of program, so perhaps this structure is justified elsewhere. Possibly better would be sth like bigram_counts[firstword][secondword] = count, that is bigram_count maps first word to the another dict that maps second word to count. It may be more expensive, but I always think that in Python we optimize for programmer ease, not performance - so whatever seems easy for You is the best :-)

Comment: @MateuszL Thanks, your solution code was very smart and short.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the method you chose for storing your data is not the best for this task. You can achieve it, of course, but maybe another storage system would be more convenient. However, if you really have to do it this way, you should try something like:

```
unigram_counts = {}
for e in bigram_counts:
    if e[0] in unigram_counts:
        unigram_counts[e[0]] += bigram_counts[e[0]]
    else:
        unigram_counts[e[0]] = bigram_counts[e[0]]
```

(not tested, but that is the idea).

Comment: Thank you so much!. Can you please suggest be about a better way for storing such data structure.